# string parsing for C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a text file that has #'s in it...It looks something like this.

```
#Stuff
1
2
3
#MoreStuff 
a
b
c
```

I am trying to use std::string::find() function to get the positions of the # and then go from there, but I'm not sure how to actually code this.

This is my attempt:

```
int pos1=0;
while(i<string.size()){
  int next=string.find('#', pos1);
  i++;}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to read?

Comment: Input from the user, given in that format. I used getline to store their input in a string

Comment: "I used getline to store their input in a string" - that was the time when you were parsing the file line by line for first time already... why not look for `#` sign there?

Comment: What I meant was what variables should get what value after this is read? For example, each section being a `std::vector<std::string>` with each element being a line and the section headers ignored.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just so you know, `string` is a *horrible* name for a variable in a C++ program using the standard lib. That aside, your sample data always has `#` in the first element of a line, so if you're reading this line-by-line, why not simply : `if (!str.empty() && str[0] == '#') { ...code... }`

Comment: What do you mean by "to get the positions of the #"? The byte position in the file? The line numbers of lines containing `#`s? The column number on a line where a `#` appears?

Comment: The code sample you posted looks like you are assuming string.size() is a static method.  Related to what WhozCraig mentioned, if you are using std::string, then you would have needed to copy the file contents into an instance of std::string and call the size/find methods on that instance, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question what you mean by "position", but it looks like you are trying to do something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream incoming{"string-parsing-for-c.txt"};
    std::string const hash{"#"};
    std::string line;
    for (auto line_number = 0U; std::getline(incoming, line); ++line_number)
    {
        auto const column = line.find(hash);
        if (std::string::npos != column)
        {
            std::cout << hash << " found on line " << line_number 
                      << " in column " << column << ".\n";
        }
    }
}
```

---

...or possibly this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream incoming{"string-parsing-for-c.txt"};
    char const hash{'#'};
    char byte{};
    for (auto offset = 0U; incoming.read(&byte, 1); ++offset)
    {
        if (hash == byte)
        {
            std::cout << hash << " found at offset " << offset << ".\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one i made a while ago... (in C)

```
int char_pos(char c, char *str) {
    char *pch=strchr(str,c);
    return (pch-str)+1;
}
```

Port it to C++ and there you go! ;)

- If : Not Found Then returns Negative.
- Else : Return 'Positive', Char's 1st found position (1st match)